# AS3 How to communicate between frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I have been writing a game in timeline code.  I want the different frames (rooms) in the game to be able to share information between each other.  Of course, timeline code is limited to the frame it is written in.

After doing quite a bit of reading ("Foundation Game Design with Flash" and a number of articles, tutorials, forums etc) I decided to employ a document class.  This did not work either.  It seems it only works for frame one but not the rest of the frames (I have four).

How can I have frame four respond to something that happpened in frame one?  For example, if the player achieves something in frame one, I want a movie clip in frame four to be visible.

Comment: Can you show some part of your document class? Let us know what you have tried.

Comment: Are you using timeline code and document class both to run the logic?

Comment: Yes, I am using both timeline code as well as a document class.  My question is really "how do you recommend that I write code that effects all frames?"  How can I make frame four respond to something that happened in frame one?

Comment: I have tried declaring stage instances in both the document class and timeline.  It seems the timeline code can send to the document class but the document class cannot store information between frames.  The only exception to this is frame one.  In the publish settings, under the settings tab (that looks like a wrench) I can export into a different frame but not multiple frames.  Is it even possible to have the actions of one frame effect another frame?  This is my question.

Answer (score 2):

If You are writing your code on the timeline, My suggestion would be to create two layers in the timeline, one for 'frame-actions' - in this layer you insert the code specific to a single frame (will work when the movieclip is stopped on that particular frame).. And also create one more layer called global-actions (for the entire timeline). Only the first frame will be a key frame and there should be empty frames till the end of the timeline. 
In this layer actions write the code that you want to access from any keyframe in the same timeline.

If you define a variable in the actions which are written for the whole timeline (global-actions) then that will be available on all the frames.

Now if you want to go to a different frame based on some action, just write some functions in the layer which contains global actions and call that particular function through the frame actions. To go to a different frame use the 'gotoAndStop(frameNumber)' function of flash.

I want to tell you that while it will work, I would not recommend using it in this way.

HTH.

Comment: Re your last sentence - I feel the same way about the answer I gave, the biggest problem with Flash is the collision between the concept of timeline/frames and scripting across them, it's often counter-intuitive or feels messy.

Comment: @Mick and Dex  It seems that in either of your answers I will need to limit the scope of the code within my game to one frame.  Since I am using Flash, I will just make many layers and handle the game logic in classes for symbols, document class, timeline code and a global actions class for the entire timeline (don't fully understand the global actions yet).  In any way, this really flips my whole approach on it's head but that is what I needed. Sadly, there doesn't seem to be any serious Flash game design books on the market. Just mostly stuff for kids.

Comment: I've not built flash games for a long time, but I used to find that scripting across different frames always caused more problems than it solved once the game gets past a certain level of complexity. You can still use frames, and take advantage of their existence, but use one frame on the main timeline, and control the playhead of child MovieClips with it. Do you have much experience with coding on other platforms?

Comment: Thanks for the input Mick.  I have noticed this as well.  Keeping everything on one frame is definitely the best way to go for gaming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static variables - these are variables which are linked to a class, rather than an instance of it.

Suppose your document class was called Document.as, and you wanted a variable, playerLives, to be visible from any part of the program.

Declare it inside Document.as:

```
public static var playerLives:int = 3;
```

You can then reference this directly from anywhere else in your code with:

```
Document.playerLives
```

(note that the variable is a member of the class itself, not an instance of it).

You could use a dedicated Statics class to hold these variables if you want to keep your document neat, or attach them to the relevant classes (eg `Player.lives`)

I've not used timeline/frames for some years but I believe this is how I used to do it!

NB Statics will be fine for your purposes but they are, in some ways, an equivalent to the `_global` variable in AS2 (at least, they can be used in the same manner) - many would not approve of their use, or over-use, as they are freely accessible from anywhere in your program (thus anathema to the OO concept of encapsulation), but personally I try not to worry about it in small cases - the most important thing to know about the rules of any design pattern is when they can be broken!

They are also slightly slower to access than instance members, but you won't notice this unless you are constantly accessing/changing them (making things like player velocity, which will need to be referenced/changed every frame, static, is not a good idea).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the simplest way to link everything with the document class is to move your four frames into a movieclip together and have that on the first frame, then interact with that movieclip.

E.g. in the document class, where the movieclip instance on the timeline is called 'game'.

```
game.gotoAndStop(4);
game.objectToDisplay.visible = true;
```

If you encounter reference errors in the IDE then you can avoid these by using [] notation to refer to the properties of game, e.g. game["objectToDisplay"].visible = true;

Note that it's not really best practice to do this, but it will at least help you to finish that first game which is really more important at this stage in your learning. Afterwards, if you want to learn more then I'd recommend "The Essential Guide to Flash Games" by Jeff Fulton from 8bitrocket.com - it will teach you how to use the document class effectively.

Comment: I have learned to avoid timeline code for all but the simplest things.  Mainly just for animating MovieClips and buttons.  The best approach, for games, that I have found is to put animation and code into symbols and then add them to the first frame.  Then use a document class to add or remove them.

Comment: @Syed Putting code into symbols is also not recommended practice (apart from at most a call to stop() to stop animations where necessary) - if you need code on an object in your library, it's better to put this in an actionscript class for that type of object, and link the symbols to the code in the properties panel. Even that isn't necessarily ideal but it does make some things easier..

Comment: @Syed Code on symbols is how it used to need to be done in the AS1/2 days, but the massive downside is it's very difficult to find (and modify) your code later, and since as a programmer you spend much more time reading code than writing it, it's a lot easier if you can find the code you need to read as quickly and easily as possible!!

Comment: @Syed Another resource you may find useful is Colin Moock's Lost Weekend video tutorials, or his book http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946 which covers identical material